# Cannot display view variable value

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

That is my controller:
(file name: AboutController.php)

```
class AboutController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

public function init()
{
    /* Initialize action controller here */
}

public function indexAction()
{
    $this->view->pageTitle="GameNomadTitle";
}

public function contactAction()
{

}


}
```

And that is my view that is Associated with it.
(file name: index.phtml)

```
    enter code here<br /><br />
<div id="view-content">


<title><?= $this->pageTitle; ?></title>


Links: Homepage – NFO


</div>
```

The title doesnt seem to be appear..why is that?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the space between the `=` and the variable you are trying to output:

```
<?=$this->pageTitle; ?>
```

better still, don't use short tags:

```
<?php echo $this->pageTitle; ?>
```